# How can I build an apk WITH a deprecated plugin on android studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

My flutter application is using a plugin that has been discontinued. The app runs well in an emulator but android studio gives out the message 'java uses or overrides a deprecated API' when I try to build an apk. I don't want to go through the hassle of finding a different plugin now and change the code everywhere. Is there a way to build the apk on android studio without having to update dependencies?
ps. I'm creating this app purely for coding practice.

Comment: Is it an error? Does the APK building process stop because of this? AFAIK this is a warning which you can neglect.

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala They're just notes, but the apk never builds. Terminal gets stuck at 'Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... '

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem and these follow steps solved my problem:

1. flutter clean
2. flutter pub get
3. flutter build `apk --release --split-per-abi`

if there is a deprecated api, it will recompile with -Xlint